# iOS error : How allowed WatchKit 2.0? - This app contains multiple WatchKit 2.0 apps. Only a single WatchKit 2.0 app is allowed

Tags: ios, apple-watch

[image]

**Error Message :**

> This app contains multiple WatchKit 2.0 apps. Only a single WatchKit
>   2.0 app is allowed.

How allowed WatchKit 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this, do a "Clean Build Folder" (press Option to see menu) and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that that your `bundle identifier` is correct in all target. your extension and your app should not have same bundle identifier. One application can contain just one Apple Watch companion app, you can not contain multiple!

You should refer [Apple Developer Forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50624) !

Answer (score 0):

Press cmd + shift + k to clean and rebuild